# how to ignore "FF FF FF FF" with python

Tags: python

i have a file around 60 kb, i am trying to extract the data only. the file has alot of "FF FF FF FF" in it and i am trying to extract everything but the "FF FF FF FF" here is an example:

```
46 0D 89 2E 16 FC 1E E6 10 C1 6D 4E 1B 74 5F 1F 
81 07 E2 E7 17 14 77 D4 EA AC BC 20 EA 98 27 FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

and here is the code i use to get it:

```
infile = open("file.bin", "rb") 
    new_pos = int("0xFC0000", 16)
    infile.seek(new_pos, 0)
    chunk = int("0x40000", 16)
    data = infile.read(chunk)
    with open("processed_file.bin", "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.write(data)
```

it will read the file and save it as "processed file.bin" but it has all these "FF FF's" in it. there are instances of FF, and i need for it to find "FF FF FF FF" and remove it from the file before it saves it as processed file.bin

any input would be appreciated.

EDIT: to further explain what i mean, this hex has FF at the end of it,

```
81 07 E2 E7 17 14 77 D4 EA AC BC 20 EA 98 27 FF
```

i need to keep that FF at the end, but remove any instances of FF FF or FF FF FF FF.

Comment: Do you only want to remove aligned `FF FF`? In other words, for `00 FF FF 03`, should the `FF FF` be removed?

Comment: yes i want to leave "FF" but remove "FF FF" or "FF FF FF" or "FF FF FF FF" if that makes any sense

Comment: Well, that doesn't directly answer my question, but the fact that you want to remove `FF FF FF` implies the answer… so let me go update my answer to explain that version.

Comment: By the way, there's no reason to do `int("0xFC0000", 16)`—it's the same thing as just `0xFC0000`.

Answer (score 0):

First, removing every `FF FF` obviously takes care of removing every `FF FF FF FF`, so you don't need to worry about that part.

If you only want to remove aligned `FF FF`s, the obvious thing to do is to group it into 2-byte chunks. For example, using `grouper` out of the standard library's [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
data = infile.read(chunk)
data_words = grouper(2, data)
data_words_minus_ffff = (word for word in data_words if word != ('\xFF', '\xFF'))
out_data = flatten(data_words_minus_ffff)
with open("processed_file.bin", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(''.join(out_data))
```

Obviously you can write this more compactly; I just did it this way for clarity (and so you can try printing out `list(…)` at each step to help understand it, in case it isn't obvious).

But what if you don't care about alignment, and you even want to remove odd runs of `FF`, as long as they're longer than 1? Well, then you want to group it into runs, and throw away any runs longer than 1. You can do this with `itertools` too:

```
data = infile.read(chunk)
groups = itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x != '\xff')
groups_listified = ((key, list(group)) for key, group in groups)
groups_without_ff_runs = (group for key, group in groups_listified if key or len(group) > 1)
out_data = flatten(groups_without_ff_runs)
with open("processed_file.bin", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(''.join(out_data))
```

This one is a bit harder to explain, but again I've written it as a sequence of separate steps, so you can `print list(…)` after each one to see what it's doing.

The `if key or len(group) > 1` bit is saying that it's a run of non-FF bytes, or it's a run of more than 1 byte. So, if you wanted to change this to only keep 2-byte FF runs, not longer ones, you'd change the `len(group) > 1` to `len(group) == 2`. If you want to just keep even-length runs, use `len(group) % 2 == 0`. And so on. Any condition you can describe, you can put there.

Or, for the sake of variety, let's do it explicitly:

```
data = infile.read(chunk)
run = 0
out_data = []
for byte in data:
    if byte == '\xFF':
        run += 1
    else:
        if run != 1:
            out_data.append('\xFF' * run)
        run = 0
        out_data.append(byte)
with open("processed_file.bin", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(''.join(out_data))
```

Again, we're keeping all runs of `FF` that are longer than 1 byte. If you instead want to keep all runs that are exactly 2 bytes, just change `run != 1` to `run == 2`. And so on.

Comment: @isedev: The OP didn't specify, but I'm pretty sure his binary file isn't actually the ASCII characters `'46 0D 89 2E …'`, but the bytes `'\x46\x0d\x89\x2e…'`. (In other words, he showed us a hex dump of the file rather than cat.) Otherwise, why would he open it in binary mode?

Comment: @abarnert... yes, realised afterwards :)

Comment: ok, i just realized, please dont shoot me ^^   but there are instances where i need to keep FF FF, and delete anything more than FF FF,

Comment: your code does work tho, but deletes 6 bytes of data, which is 3 instances of FF FF, so i need to keep FF FF and delete anything more

Comment: @james28909: If you want to keep all runs that are not exactly 2 bytes long, just change `len(group) == 1` to `len(group) != 2` (or, equivalently, `if run == 1` to `if run != 2` for the more explicit solution).

Comment: if i change if run == 1 to anything else, it changes the filesize dramatically. if i use if run != 2 it prints FF's randomly through the hex...... when i use if run == 1 the file is only 6 bytes short

Comment: Sorry, I got that backward in the comments. You want `run == 2` to keep runs of length 2, but not shorter or longer. Let me edit the answer to remove some confusion. But really, you need to understand what this code does, not just treat it as a magical invocation. If you don't understand it, try printing out what's happening at each step (with a very short block of input, so you don't get overwhelmed). If it isn't clear to you how to change the condition from "all FF runs longer than 1" to "all FF runs of exactly length 2", you will have a nightmare debugging it a few months from now.

Comment: ok, i am a beginner with python, or coding all together, but i am learning, and you guys here really know what yall are doing.i think alot of things i am just trying to over think and that is where the problems and overwhelming sensations come in :P

Comment: @james28909: That's OK. Some things actually are difficult. Or, worse, they're simple at an abstract level that you haven't learned yet, but difficult at the level of things you have learned. (Well, that's actually _better_ in the long run, but worse in the short run… you know what I mean.) Anyway, the more you take the time to step through how things work and try to understand them, the faster you'll get to the point where all the simple stuff is simple, and you can start spending all day debugging dumb typos like the rest of us. :)

Comment: how about this, let me upload you the file and code, that way you can see exactly what i mean. i will also upload what it should look like.

Comment: and like i said, its 6-7 bytes short, and when i change it to ==2 or !=1 or!=2  it changes the filesize dramatically. i am using python 2.7 btw

Comment: Well… `run != 1` or `run != 2` are going to fire when run is 0. And your code appends `'\xFF'` instead of `'\xFF' * run` like the answer. So it's adding an extra `FF` character after each non-`FF` (and also turning each `FFFF` into a single `FF`). Anyway, using `run == 2` removes 771 bytes instead of 768 because of that second bug. Also, I would use the `itertools` solution instead of the explicit one, because it's harder to get wrong. You're just specifying which values get kept, instead of trying to write out the algorithm to re-add skipped-over runs (which I've screwed up twice).